# Steering and wall hugging problem

Tags: steering-behaviors

What I'm hoping to achieve is that when the player steers into a wall the movement is smoothed out by hugging along the wall, moving only with the velocity parallel to the wall, zeroing out the normal force) rather than bouncing back from the wall using the "generic" avoidance method.

I want this: [image]Not this:[image]

The two images are actual behaviors from my code. One removes the velocity normal to the wall so it glides smoothly hugging the wall. The other steers away from the wall creating the bouncing effect. The latter case actually works quite reliably but I do not like the bouncing behavior.

Here's my design for the for handling this case:

1. The vertical wall is actually made up of many square tiles
2. The wall avoidance steering checks one unit ahead to see if it is in contact with a tile
3. The normal is determined by which edge on the tile I'm closest to
4. zero out the velocity of the player normal to the wall

However this is not reliable for several reasons:

- in the gif above, if the look ahead ends up on the bottom edge of a tile, it gets the wrong normal (goes horizontal instead)
- the player can get stuck if it happens to penetrate the wall to much (i.e. stay on track for 1 frame, then next frame gets the wrong/perpendicular normal, then both velocities are canceled out)
- player can penetrate the wall quite easily if they pick the right spot (which I don't have an obvious sense why)

I am wondering if anyone has a better suggestion on how to handle this case? The only requirement that I prefer to keep is the tile based wall as I have a map editor that generates the map data. Also if there is a method that can be extended to sloped walls that would be even better!

Thanks!

Comment: Development platform??

Comment: Did you try to set friction to zero? Of player and wall? If not, then try it

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, only hides it.

Comment: have you considered a*?

Comment: I'm using Cocos2dx, not using any physics framework so no friction is involved. As a matter of fact I am already using A* (with JPS), but disabled for for this demo as I was testing out steering behaviors. The problem with A* is one: the unit can go on the wall if the path happens to hug the wall, two: doesn't work well for dynamic obsticles. So I'm hoping to use steering to make movement look more natural along with A*.

Comment: Working on a partial answer now, but can you clarify a bit on "it gets the wrong normal" in issue #1? I know what you're describing, but it sounds like it _should_ go horizontally if it hits the bottom side of the wall. Do you mean that it's hitting the bottom of one of the middle wall tiles, and that drives it straight at the wall? Something else?

Comment: so what I meant by "wrong normal" is: frame 1 -> the normal (horizontal velocity) is removed from the unit by steering against the normal
, frame 2 ->unit continues moving vertically, doing the same thing above
, frame 3 (or until it reaches next tile)-> if the unit happens to be on the wall, the look ahead of this frame gets the underside of the tile, which gives the vertical normal, canceling out its vertical velocity. Because I'm still touching the wall, I cannot resume seek behavior until I steer away from the wall, thus both x and y velocities are neutralized and the character gets stuck

Comment: I also tried shifting away from the wall on contact but seek steering will interfere with it, and using 3 probes at 45 degrees each and prioritizing which probe is checked first to optimize the which normal should be correct. But they all create more problems than they solve.